# Flatten dataframe cell of comma separated list (not list type) in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have  created a DF that contains a cell that is created by this:

```
sectionsdf.loc[i, 'DrillerID'] = ',| '.join(drillerID)
```

After the fact, i am needing to flatten this cell so that each ID has its own row but with all the other data that is found in that row.

```
A     B      C      D
1     2      3      a,| b
6     7      8      c,| d,| e


#####  Desired Results  ######


A     B       C      D
1     2       3      a
1     2       3      b
6     7       8      c
6     7       8      d
6     7       8      e
```

My first thought is to loop through the list and inserting rows.  But i figured there has to be a better way to do it.

Any ideas?

Thanks

BD

EDIT:

I changed the list column from numbers to what it acutally is in my data (for the most part)

Comment: Just in case you didn't gather this from the dup target `df.iloc[np.arange(len(df)).repeat(df.D.str.count(',\s*') + 1)].assign(D=[*map(int, ','.join(df.D).split(','))])`

Comment: that doesn't seem to be working.  I changed my post to more accurately show what my data shows.  would that change anything?

Comment: `df.iloc[np.arange(len(df)).repeat(df.D.str.count(r',\|\s*') + 1)].assign(D=',| '.join(df.D).split(',| '))`

Comment: Thanks, i think i got it figured out!!